# proyeto en cakephp me redirige a la pagina del cliente en localhost

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

Tengo un proyecto que descargue del servidor de produccion, cuando lo quiero utilizar en localhost me redirige a la pagina del cliente.

Creo que el problema es en htaccess y me esta redirigiendo a la pagina del cliente.

```
htaccess

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Uncomment if you have a .well-known directory in the root folder, e.g. for the Let's Encrypt challenge
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    #RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteEngine On 
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.com/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz


</IfModule>
```

cuando cambio el RewriteRule a esto:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost.com/proyecto/$1 [R,L]
```

continua redirigiendome a la pagina del cliente.

Comment: Si trabajas en linux usa `grep` de modo recursivo para buscar el nombre de dominio entre los archivos del código de tu web, a ver si está en algun archivo de configuración o hardcodeado en alguna parte que está forzando ese redireccionamiento en lugar de ir a tu localhost. Si usas windows ni idea, algo tendrá para eso supongo. Si no lo encuentras haz la búsqueda en la base de datos.

Comment: trabajo con windows , gracias por el comentario